# How can I transform dataframe using pd.melt

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', 'lunch', 70], 
                   ['Bob', 'dinner', 160], 
                   ['Sara', 'lunch', 150], 
                   ['Sara', 'dinner', 220]], 
                  columns=['Name', 'Meal', 'Cost'])
```

```
   Name    Meal  Cost
0   Bob   lunch    70
1   Bob  dinner   160
2  Sara   lunch   150
3  Sara  dinner   220
```

How can I transform the dataframe into the following using `pd.melt` or any other way?

```
   Name   Meal_1  Cost_1   Meal_2  Cost_2
0   Bob   lunch       70   dinner     160
1  Sara   lunch      150   dinner     220
```

Comment: Do you want a general arbitrarily wide wide-to-long output, or a pivot, where we can assume there was at most one lunch and one dinner (or <= 2 meals) per person? ) Suggest using a pivot as @buhtz says.

Answer (score 2):

#### a) This looks more like a job for `pivot()` not `melt()`.

```
df.pivot(index=['Name'], columns=['Meal'], values=['Cost'])
```

The result is a pivot-table:

```
       Cost
Meal dinner lunch
Name
Bob     160    70
Sara    220   150
```

Not exactly what you want but maybe better.

#### b) Alternative: wide-form table

```
     Meal_1  Cost_1  Meal_2  Cost_2
Name
Bob   lunch      70  dinner     160
Sara  lunch     150  dinner     220
```

...which you can get with code like this:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
lunch = df.loc[df.Meal.eq('lunch')]
dinner = df.loc[df.Meal.eq('dinner')]
df = pd.concat([lunch, dinner], axis=1)
df.columns = ['Meal_1', 'Cost_1', 'Meal_2', 'Cost_2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [1293]: x = df.groupby('Name').agg(list)

In [1333]: splits = [pd.DataFrame(x[col].tolist(), index=x.index).add_prefix(col + '_') for col in x.columns]

In [1338]: res = pd.concat(splits, axis=1).reset_index()

In [1339]: res
Out[1339]: 
   Name Meal_0  Meal_1  Cost_0  Cost_1
0   Bob  lunch  dinner      70     160
1  Sara  lunch  dinner     150     220
```